# Firebase and Ionic 2 Autocomplete

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to do an autocomplete input in an ionic 2 app. It is for selecting the country and ideally after 3 characters the query will start to firebase and then output the options under the text field - the json is structured like so

```
    {
        "country ": {
            "BD": "Bangladesh",
            "BE": "Belgium",
            "BF": "Burkina Faso",
            "BG": "Bulgaria",
            "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
            "BB": "Barbados",
            "WF": "Wallis and Futuna",
            "BL": "Saint Barthelemy",
            "BM": "Bermuda",
            "BN": "Brunei"
        }
    }
```

What I really need is to skip the key so skip BD and go straight for Bangladesh as the user types "Bang" my function for doing so looks like so i have also tried adding startAt(country).endAt(country) but it didnt work either.

```
selectCountry(){
    const country = this.country;
    if( country.length >= 3){
        fire.instance().database().ref('country').on('value', (snapshot) => {
                const msg = snapshot.val(); 
                console.log("country " + msg);   
              });    
    }
}
```

and the html for the component looks like so

```
<ion-list>
<ion-list-header>
  Country
</ion-list-header>
<ion-item>
<ion-input (input)="selectCountry($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="country" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a static node on firebase? As the user is typing or on this view can he insert more data on the country node?

If not, what you're doing is bad because at every time the user type it'll make a call to the DB.

It would be better if you do like this:

---

Use the NavController ´ionViewWillLoad()` method and get everything from the country node and save to a variable. As you don't want to know the key you have to iterate through the promise:

```
countries: any[] = [];
ionViewWillEnter(){
  fire.instance().database().ref('country').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    for (var c in snapshot.val()){
      this.countries.push(snapshot.val()[c]);
      console.log("country " + snapshot.val()[c]); 
    }
  });  
}
```

Create an initialize method that you'll use to reset the countries and a variable for the filtered ones:

```
countriesFiltered: any[];
initialize(){ this.countriesFiltered = this.countries; }
```

Create a filter method like the one on Ionic 2 docs, you don't need to pass the $event.target.value, just the $event:

```
selectCountry(ev: any) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initialize();

  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  let val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.countriesFiltered= this.countriesFiltered.filter((item) => {
      return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

With this you call the database just one to get all the countries, save them in a variable that you can use more easily. If you want you can use a loading to prevent the user from clicking anywhere or start searching without having all countries ready.

If there if a view later that is inputing more countries you can use `ionViewWillEnter()` intead of `ionViewWillLoad()`.

WillEnter executes every time you enter that view if you go back and forth, WillLoad executes just one time when you're entering it and if the view is destroyed/unloaded and you enter it again.

Hope it helps :D

### EDIT

And, if you don't know, you need to show your countries somewhere on the screen, so use a `*ngFor` with cards or something like this to show and filter, like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let c of countriesFiltered">
    <!-- with searchbar always use the filtered variable -->
        {{c}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This looks like a bloody good example - but sadly its not working for me, I like the logic so Im going to try mess around with it but if you know of why it might not be output any results that would be cool too. thanks for this though. FYI: its a static node and no the user cannot edit or add to this. its just for display and then they will be able to click it and it will update their profile.